# NSOutlineView, NSTreeController and willDisplayCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I'm pretty new to Obj-C and Cocoa stuff, so forgive any stupidity.

I'm using an NSOutlineView with an NSTreeController that provides an array of my own objects to it. My delegator is using the outline view's willDisplayCell to set the icon of the cell (I'm using NSBrowserCell). I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get my object data in that instance so that I can check which image to draw, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

You have to use

```
[item representedObject];
```